# unable to adjust mysql timeouts

Tags: mysql, sql

I've done the following:

```
SET GLOBAL wait_timeout = 5;
SET SESSION wait_timeout = 5;
SET GLOBAL interactive_timeout = 5;
SET SESSION interactive_timeout = 5;
```

But when I run a time consuming query it's still losing the connection at 600 seconds - not 5 seconds. I'm doing the queries in the same MySQL Workbench tab, one after the other, so it should all be in the same session..

I also tried updating `C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\my.ini` and adding `wait_timeout=5` and...  nothing.

Any ideas?

Also, why, when one time consuming query is running on 127.0.0.1 in one tab, can't I do `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` in another tab?

Answer (score 0):

`wait_timeout` only controls how long a connection can be *idle* before the server closes it.  If you're executing a query that takes a long time, then that variable has nothing to do with your issue.

There is nothing built in to MySQL which will kill active running queries after a set time.  So there is something else causing that to happen.  And you need to give more information.

When you say "it's closing the connection"  What *exactly* happens?  Do you receive an error in your program, if so what is it?  How are you running the program?